# clarity about Xcode 6 constraints

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios8, constraints

I have an app that I am in the process of updating from iOS 7 to 8 and trying to take advantages of the new size classes Apple now offers. The one thing that I just seem to be having tons of trouble with is how the constraint system works. I've worked through some tutorial and look at other postings, and things still don't seem to be working in my favor.

First I will explain my file structure as well a provide some images, just in case I'm not clear on what I have.

My View Controller is set up like so:

View Controller
View
   Navigation Bar
   Keyboard Avoid Scroll View (UIScrollView)
      View
         What Kind (child View)
         NameOFBill
         AmountOwedView
         OptionalView
         ReminderView
         Save
And here is a screen grab of that structure: [image]

For my constraints I set the Navigation Bar and the Keyboard Avoiding (UIScrollView) to 0 top right left and bottom. See Image below.
[image]

Now up until this point, all is going well. Xcode is NOT complaining about anything missing.

So up next is the View inside the scrollView which I am using as a container for all the content inside the scrollView. When I try to repeat the process from about I get some constraint warnings.... but why? I gave it a constraint on the top right left and bottom, why is that not enough for Xcode to know how why and tall it should be. It seems that is wants a width and height for the view as well. Buy if I set the width, then it assumes the width of 600 which is much too wide for any iPhone.

I'm sure my thinking is not correct somewhere.. i just don't know where and why. I truly want to understand how this system works, so any insight be would helpful

Thanks!!

** Update **

Here is what the inspector looks like
:[image]

And here is what Xcode is complaining about
 [image]

Comment: Could you select the view and look what constraints it has in the Size Inspector in the right panel. If you could post a screenshot, that would help. Setting the 4 spacing constraints should be enough, so I wonder if you have some other constraints for that view that conflict one another.

Comment: Have you added constraints for the subviews of UIScrollview?

Comment: Only for the direct subview inside the UIScrollView, but when I do what is mentioned above, thats when the error comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIScrollView`'s are a special case when it comes to constraints. The constraints on the immediate child of the `UIScrollView` actually set the contentSize of the scroll view. It's actually quite powerful, as it means you can fill that `UIView` with stuff, and as long as you have set all the constraints appropriately it will automatically set the contentSize of the `UIScrollView` without you having to do anything in code. You will get an "ambiguous scrollable content" warning however if you don't have constraints pinning the child `UIView` to the scroll view in every direction, as this is how it figures out what the contentSize is.

However, this means that you can't expect the child `UIView` pinned to the left and right of the `UIScrollView` to match the width of the `UIScrollView`, because the width by default is determined by it's contents.

There is a way around this however. You can select both the `UIScrollView` and the `UIView` in Interface Builder, and add an "Equal Widths" constraint. This will get around the setting of the contentSize, and actually match the width of the `UIView` to the frame width of the `UIScrollView`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the "Misplaced Views" warning by selecting the view and pressing Command+Option+=. This updates the frame of the view to match the constraints it has. The warning basically says that the constraints of the view don't march its frame as it appears in Interface Builder.

The "Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity" message is probably due to the fact that the views inside your scroll view are lacking some constraints. If IB can't determine where those views should be placed, it can't set the contentSize of the scroll view correctly. Go through your views inside the scroll view and make sure they don't miss any constraints.

EDIT:

On the screenshot below you can see how you can either update the frame of a view (same as pressing Command+Option+=), OR do the opposite: update the constraints based on the current position of the view in IB. Try clicking "Update Constraints" (or even "Reset to Suggested Constraints") if you think your view is positioned correctly in IB, and you want your constraints to match that positioning.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When I press  Command+Option+= the view completely disappears.. i think it's pushing it off to the far left side of the ScrollView

Comment: That means that your constraints are incorrect. What this key combination does is forcing IB to recalculate the visible frame based on the current constraints of the view.

Comment: so in the warning.. why is it expecting a height and width of 0 , 0? That's what happens when I press update frame.. it sets the height and width to 0, 0 instead of 600 x600 like it should be from the constraints I created.... Does that make sense?

Comment: Hard to say, but one reason why that could happen is if the superview itself has incorrect constraints.

Comment: If I also select the width and hight, it no longer gives me warnings.. but he issue then is the width of the view is set to 600, and causes the view to be able to scroll horizontally. What is the best way to check the super views constraints?

Comment: Just select the superview in IB and look at its constraints, just like you would do it with any other view. If something's wrong, the IB should show some orange or red frames or lines, indicating the problem.

Comment: Would this warning effect the scroll view? UIScrollView+TPKeyboardAvoidingAdditions.m:238:144: Comparison of distinct pointer types ('id<NSFileManagerDelegate>' and 'UIScrollView *')

Comment: or this one: Sending 'UIScrollView *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSFileManagerDelegate>'

Comment: I tried to google those warnings and nothing really came back

Comment: also I selected the parent view and all the constraints are blue, and seem fine. I just don't know why the child view won't adobe to the parent size.

Comment: The last 2 errors you mention have nothing to do with Auto Layout. They're separate coding issues. I recommend creating a new question/questions for those if you need help with them.

Comment: Thanks BlackRider, so as I was saying before. I opened up a new file, it has one ViewController. I drug on a scroll view and pinned the top right left bottom all to 0. Then I placed a view inside of the scrollView and tried to do the same thing, pin the top right left and bottom. When I do that I get the warnings of Misplaced views: expected width=0, height=0. Actual: width=600, height=600. Why would it expect 0 for the width and hight when I pinned the scrollView which I thought would act as the parent to the View?